# Multiplicative inverse of Weyl symbol and invertibility of operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, phase-space, wigner-transform

If the Weyl symbol $A_W$ of an operator $\hat{A}$ has a multiplicative inverse at every point of the phase-space, can I conclude that $\hat{A}$ is invertible?

Comment: Weyl symbols compose through the $\star$-product. What makes you suspect plain multiplication suffices for $\star$-invertibility, which is tantamount to operator invertibility? Are you looking for counterexamples?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @CosmasZachos. I know about the Moyal product composition, but I was just wondering if the answer to my question was positive. In case the idea does not hold, a counter-example would suffice.

Comment: I will keep thinking about it. Perhaps something on the line you suggested could lead to a counter-example. Thanks again.

Comment: You might mean that if $A_W(x,p)$ has no zeros, then it has no zero star-gen-values, $A_W\star f(x,p)=0$...?

Comment: Yes, I believe this would answer my question.

Comment: Isn't it enough that the ground and first excited states of the SHO Wigner functions are *-orthogonal, $f_0\star f_1=0 $, whereas $f_0\propto e^{-(x^2+p^2)/\hbar}$ is manifestly invertible as a function? So, if you Weyl-transforme these two, you find $\hat f_0 \hat f_1=0$, and hitting any state on the right, automatically produces a null state for $\hat f_0$. Looks like a fine counterexample to me, if you use these as the suitable Weyl symbols!

Comment: Yes, this is a simple, yet great, counterexample. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I saw you wrote it up as an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. Consider the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator, and take
$$
\hat A= |\psi_0\rangle \langle \psi_0|, ~~~~\mapsto ~A_W=f_0\propto e^{-(x^2+p^2)/\hbar},$$
which has a multiplicative inverse, except at infinity.

But the eigenstates of the oscillator are orthogonal, so
for any eigenstate ψ with a first excited component, the state
$$
|\psi_1\rangle \langle \psi_1|\psi\rangle \neq 0,
$$
while
$$
\hat A |\psi_1\rangle \langle \psi_1|\psi\rangle =0.
$$
This presents as $f_0\star f_1=0$ in phase space, magically valid at every point in phase space!

So $\hat A$ has a nonempty kernel, i.e. zero eigenvalues, and is not invertible.